# How to strip folder names in py_library imports?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I'm having a problem understanding the python import directories of bazel.
Given a tree like this:

```
.
├── WORKSPACE
├── python_lib_a/
│   ├── BUILD
│   └── src/
│       └── package1/
│           └── folder1/
│               └── some_file.py
└── python_binary_a/
    ├── BUILD
    └── src/
        └── package1/
            └── folder2/
                └── python_binary.py
```

How can the `python_binary.py` file import the `some_file.py` file like this:

```
from package1.folder1.some_file import SomeClass
```

I'm pretty new to Bazel, so my google queries could be wrong. I could not find any example of removing/stripping folder names.
I'm willing to write custom rules, if necessary. Something like a plugin that changes the folders during compiling.

**EDIT**: In addition to the accepted answer, I had to do add this to the `package1/__init__.py` files in both the library and the binary src folders:

```
import pkgutil
__path__ = pkgutil.extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably a way to do this but a way that would definitely work is to move the position of your `BUILD` files

```
.
├── WORKSPACE
├── python_lib_a/
│   └── src/
│       ├── BUILD
│       └── package1/
│           └── folder1/
│               └── some_file.py
└── python_binary_a/
    └── src/
        ├── BUILD
        └── package1/
            └── folder2/
                └── python_binary.py
```

Then in `python_lib_a` it would be like below and called from `//python_lib_a/src:package1`

```
py_library(
    name = "package1",
    srcs = glob(
        ["package1**/**/*.py"],
    ),
    imports = ["."],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Then in the other one do

```
py_library(
    name = "package2",
    srcs = glob(
        ["package1**/**/*.py"],
    ),
    imports = ["."],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [ '//python_lib_a/src:package1']
)
```

Comment: I think you could do this without moving the build files. Then you would have `imports = ["src"]`.

Comment: Looking at the generated PYTHONPATH environment variable the problem seems to be solved but I still get an import error. This time it is not `No module named package1` but it is `No module named package1.folder2`.

Comment: solved it by: `import pkgutil; 
__path__ = pkgutil.extend_path(__path__, __name__)`